# Why is selenium hanging on INFO - Checking Resource aliases, and how do I even debug this?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](http://www.labelmedia.co.uk/blog/posts/setting-up-selenium-server-on-a-headless-jenkins-ci-build-machine.html) to setup a headless selenium test-run with jenkins. I'm running CentOS 5.6, and I've followed the instructions. Now, when I run this:

`export DISPLAY=":99" && java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -browserSessionReuse -htmlSuite *firefox http://www.google.com ./test/selenium/html/TestSuite.html ./target/selenium/html/TestSuiteResults.html`

Selenium hangs on `INFO - Checking Resource Aliases`. I can run the `TestSuite.html` file manually, and the path is correct.

How can I even begin to try and figure out what's going on? Is there a way I could connect to the display to see what's happening? I am behind a corporate proxy, but with or without `-Dhttp.proxyHost` arguments, I get the same hung result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after pointing at an internal server, I get right on past the `INFO - Checking Resource Aliases` step, so clearly the proxy was the issue.

By trying to hit a site that required the proxy, I was doing too much at once. Confounding variables confounded me.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium is not hanging on `INFO - Checking Resource Aliases`. Its waiting for a command to execute. You need to trigger your tests using ANT or some other build tool in Jenkins. That should get you going